# perl, Mail::CheckUser fails on make test

Tags: perl

trying to install the module on Linux, but failing on make test..

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/smtp-taint.t (Wstat: 0 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/smtp.t      (Wstat: 0 Tests: 4 Failed: 1)
Failed test:  1
t/wildcard.t  (Wstat: 0 Tests: 13 Failed: 3)
Failed tests:  8-9, 12
Files=6, Tests=59, 21 wallclock secs ( 0.05 usr  0.01 sys +  0.51   cusr  0.08 csys =  0.65 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 3/6 test programs. 4/59 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
ILYAM/Mail-CheckUser-1.21.tar.gz
/usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module,    try:
reports ILYAM/Mail-CheckUser-1.21.tar.gz
Running make install
make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

Edit:
I still can not install it via cpan.

The reason why I preferred this one to Email::Valid is that Mail::CheckUser can check if such user actually exists, not sure about right terminology... If say, mike@mike-klemin.com is OK by both  Email::Valid and Mail::CheckUser, but if you try notmike@mike-klemin.com, Email::Valid still says it's OK, while Mail::CheckUser will report that there no such user. 
May be I missed some functionality of Email::Valid and it can do that too.

Comment: I don't think this is off topic at all as a "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error" nor was it "resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers". It can be reproduced. Anyone installing Mail::CheckUser will run into the same problem. My answer points to a patch to allow anyone else installing that module to fix the problem. The answers also cover why the technique used in the module is flawed as well as alternative modules.

Comment: @Schwern: One *hopes* it means that the close voters tried to reproduce the problem but did not succeed.  But, um, that close reason is really only supposed to be used if **even the OP** doesn't have the problem anymore, so I'm voting to reopen it.

Comment: For better or worse, the close reason is just the prevailing one; it's not necessarily the case that all votes were made using that reason. Given there has been no change to the post since it was vote closed, it's hard to see why it should be reopened, even if the close reason seems off. Probably should have been closed as "unclear what you're asking" instead, since the only actual question here is "Should I?" But looks to me like it should still stay closed, at least until the question is improved.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I believe it has been fully answered, reopening is a meta issue. I'd like it to be reopened because I consider questions about failing Perl module tests to be on topic. Also so future folks don't see it and think "oh, my question is off topic, I guess I won't ask". The question may not have been worded the best, but Dave and I figured it out well enough. We've seen *a lot* of "this Perl module's tests are failing, what do I do" questions.

Comment: @SamB If they can't reproduce the problem that would be amazing, because as Dave pointed out, [everybody else can](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/M/Mail-CheckUser.html?oncpan=1&distmat=1&version=1.21).

Comment: @Schwern: Well, my point was that I only think it makes sense to use that close reason after OP says something to the effect of "nevermind, it's working now". (Or if it was a typo.)

Answer (score 2):

Always worth checking the CPAN page for a module you're having trouble with. [In this case](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::CheckUser), you'll see that CPAN Testers is reporting 2 passes and 710 failures for the latest version of the module. The [CPAN Testers page](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/M/Mail-CheckUser.html?oncpan=1&distmat=1&version=1.21) gives more details - this module hasn't tested successfully for any version of Perl more recent than 5.8.8!

Also worth noting (again on the [CPAN page](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::CheckUser)) that the most recent version was released in 2001. This module has obviously been abandoned by its author.

Those two signs (the huge number of test failures and the lack of recent versions) mean that this is a module I would be very unlikely to use on any of my projects.

Note that [Email::Valid](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Valid) seems to do much the same thing and is maintainined.

Answer (score 2):

[Mail::CheckUser](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::CheckUser) is doing more than just checking if an email address is valid syntax.  It also checks that the hostname is valid *and* asks that domain's mail server if the email address exists.  That last one is the problem.

Since the module hasn't been updated in 12 years, it's likely the assumptions in their network tests are no longer valid.

1. Certain email addresses exist (or don't)
2. Certain domains exist (or don't)
3. The mail servers will respond to verification commands

To fix the tests you can [look at the Debian source](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libmail-checkuser-perl) (which is upstream from Ubuntu) and [apply their patches](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libm/libmail-checkuser-perl/libmail-checkuser-perl_1.21-2.debian.tar.gz).  You can even [apply to take over the module](http://www.cpan.org/misc/cpan-faq.html#How_maintain_module) and upload a patched version.

Even if you fixed the tests, I doubt the technique of asking a mail server is still valid.  A lot has changed in the email world in 12 years.  I suspect many mail servers will no longer validate email addresses, it can be used by spammers to find targets and attackers to find usernames.

As [Dave suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28115332/14660), use [Email::Valid](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Valid).  It checks for valid syntax and (optionally) a valid hostname. It's well maintained and the author is *very* familiar with email.